# Disable validation on a @Html.TextBox in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.textbox

I have a form in which I want to disable the required validation on one of the @Html.TextBox elements. The front end is as follows:

```
@model Models.NewUser

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account"))
{
    <div class="field">
        <span class="textOverField absolute em1-2" style="top:6px;left:4px;">Key</span>
        @Html.TextBox("SchoolGroupKey", "", new { @class = "textField" }) 
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <span class="textOverField absolute em1-2" style="top:6px;left:4px;">Name</span>
         @Html.TextBox("Names", "", new { @class = "textField" }) <div class="absolute validationMessage">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Names)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <span class="textOverField absolute em1-2" style="top:6px;left:4px;">Last Name</span>
        @Html.TextBox("LastNames", "", new { @class = "textField" }) <div class="absolute validationMessage">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.LastNames)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="em0-9" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <input class="submitButton cursorHand" style="margin-top:10px;" type="submit" value="Registrarme" />
    </div>
}
```

And the code for the model is as follows:

```
public class NewUser
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name required")]
    public string Names { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name required")]
    public string LastNames { get; set; }

    public System.Guid SchoolGroupKey { get; set; }
}
```

I'm guessing that the @Html.TextBox has a default validation even though I don't specify it. Is there someway to remove it?, I tried removing the html tags data-val-required and data-val, but still no results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Guid` is a structure that behave as a simple type (just like `int` or `DateTime`). As such it is automaticly validated. If you want to make a workaround change your property type from `Guid` to nullable `Guid?`. Example:

```
public System.Guid? SchoolGroupKey { get; set; }
```

Of course you will have to change places when you use this property, to access the guid value throught `Value` property of nullable type.

If the mapping fails you will not get any validation errors then - just `null` value inside of your `SchoolGroupKey` property.

Comment: It shouldn't be complaining about SchoolGroupKey, since it is not marked as required.  It should just pass a new Guid to the action method.

Comment: Did you ever tried to pass wrong value into simple type like `int` or `Guid`? Of course it will return a validation error.. That's the diffrence between mapping those types and referenced ones..

Comment: Never thought about it being nullable in the model, let me check it and get back to you if this works

Comment: @triangulito if you don't want to use a `Nullable<Guid>` you can capture the `Guid` as a `string` and then validate it in the controller or domain service.

Comment: @Xander - true, but with `Guid?` he does not have to handle `Guid` parsing on his own..

Comment: It worked, didn't even have to change much in the application for it to work correctly. Thank you very much